# Design SQL table to get data from different SQL query at regular intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I ma trying to capture cpu usage of my current SQL server over a time period and came across a query from [here](https://github.com/MadeiraData/MadeiraToolbox/blob/master/Monitoring%20Scripts/CPU%20utilization%20(based%20on%20RING_BUFFER_SCHEDULER_MONITOR).sql)

Please guide me how can i use the above query to insert the results in permanent table over collected period of time without overwriting timestamp values or duplicating entries?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps an Agent Job https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4848/getting-started-with-sql-server-agent-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a scheduled job to execute the query and insert data into your table

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/schedule-a-job?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Thanks, but that is my question how do you take the query results and design a table to insert its results.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the syntax

```
INSERT INTO dbo.sysUseLig 
SELECT --the query
```

Having previously created your table dbo.sysUseLig with columns with the correct data types you will have what you need.
There is a timestamp based column in the select.